# How can I validate that a string holds only zeroes and ones?

Tags: ruby, string, validation

I have a string which should ONLY be made up of `0` and `1`. If the string has any other characters (including special characters) then the validation should return false; otherwise it should return a true.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def only_0_and_1(str)
  return !!(str =~ /^(0|1)+$/)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Regexp#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

```
s = '11er0'
# means other character present except 1 and 0
/[^10]/ === s # => true 

s = '1100'
# means other character not present except 1 and 0
/[^10]/ === s # => false
```

Here is a method :

```
def only_1_and_0(s)
  !(/[^10]/ === s)
end

only_1_and_0('11012') # => false
only_1_and_0('1101') # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes your method will always receive a string; it doesn't perform any coercion or type checking. Feel free to add that if you need it.

```
def binary? str
  ! str.scan(/[^01]/).any?
end
```

This will scan the string for any characters other than zero or one using [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-scan), and then returns an inverted Boolean that evaluates to false if [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) is true, meaning that other characters are present in the string. For example:

```
binary? '1011'
#=> true

binary? '0b1011'
#=> false

binary? '0xabc'
#=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
str.chars.any?{|c| c!='0' && c!='1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def binary?
  str.count("^01").zero?
end
```